# Filter friend picker view controller in ios

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to filter the facebook friend picker controller to show only friends who have the application. Which api do i use to check if a user has authorized the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Graph API User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) has the `installed` field, and the [FQL User table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) has the column `is_app_user`.

If you want to filter the friends yourself, you can go with the API; if you want to only get the already filtered list, then use FQL.

Comment: How I can use it to filter friends in `FBFriendPickerViewController`